# Progress bar to visualize for loop ETA

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I have this line in my code

```
lev_similarity = -1*np.array([[distance.levenshtein(w1,w2) for w1 in words] for w2 in words])
```

It takes a long time so I would like to include a progress bar with an ETA to show me the estimated time of processing.

How do I include a progress bar given this internal loop?

My approach:

```
npa = []
akt = 1
with progressbar.ProgressBar(max_value=len(words)) as bar:
    for w2 in words:
        bar.update(akt)
        akt = akt + 1
        for w1 in words:
            npa.append(distance.levenshtein(w1,w2))
lev_similarity = -1*np.array(npa)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The TQDM library (https://pypi.org/project/tqdm/) provides a very easy interface for progress bars in python.

It would become s.t.h. like:

```
from tqdm import tqdm

... code ...

new_arr = -1*np.array([[distance.levenshtein(w1,w2) for w1 in words] for w2 in tqdm(words)])
```

There is a section on nested loops in the tqdm manual.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a loop inside a loop instead of the list comprehension, and in the inner or outer loop update the progress bar.
If you still want the list comprehension, you can define a function that both performs the calculation and updates the progress bar, like so:

```
def calc(w1, w2):
    update_progress_bar()
    return distance.levenshtein(w1,w2)
```

And the list comprehension then will become:

```
 -1*np.array([[calc(w1,w2) for w1 in words] for w2 in tqdm(words)])
```

IMO a list comprehension should only create values and not cause any side effects, so although short and arguably elegant, I would go with a loop in a loop. It's more SW engineering friendly in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You're close. The implementation you have now is wrong because your bar length isn't `len(words)` but `len(words) ** 2` and you should update every operation. Furthermore, you're trying to build a 1D array when a 2D array is required. So, try this:

```
npa = []
akt = 1
num_words = len(words)
with progressbar.ProgressBar(max_value = num_words ** 2) as bar:
    for w2 in words:
        for w1 in words:
            npa.append(distance.levenshtein(w1,w2))
            bar.update(akt)
            akt = akt + 1
lev_similarity = -1*np.array(npa).reshape(num_words, num_words)
```

This way you'll update the bar every time you calculate the distance.

Comment: Not the same: ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
array=[   0 -106....]. Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.

Comment: @Alex Sorry, I thought your only issue was the progress bar, rather than a `ValueError`. I have updated my answer to reflect these issues

Comment: Thanks. Now I get `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'reshape'`, pointing at `lev_similarity = -1*np.array(npa.reshape(num_words, num_words))`

Answer (score 0):

I use my own little function to do that. I think it may work in your case as well.

```
def print_pbar(n,m,s='|#.|',size=30,message=''):
    '''(int,int,string,int) => None
    Print a progress bar using the simbols in 's'.
    Example:
        range_limit = 1000
        for n in range(range_limit):
            print_pbar(n+1,m=range_limit)
            time.sleep(0.1)
    '''
    #adjust to bar size
    if m != size:
        n =(n*size)/m
        m = size
    #calculate ticks
    _a = int(n)*s[1]+(int(m)-int(n))*s[2]
    _b = round(n/(int(m))*100,1)
    #adjust overflow
    if _b >= 100:
        _b = 100.0
    #to stdout    
    sys.stdout.write(f'\r{message}{s[0]}{_a}{s[3]} {_b}%     ')
    sys.stdout.flush()


npa = []
for n, w2 in enumerate(words):
    print_pbar(n+1, len(words))
    for w1 in words:
        npa.append(distance.levenshtein(w1,w2))
```